# Interpreting coefficents of elastic-net for ordered factors in R

Tags: interpretation, glmnet, elastic-net

I am currently learning the `elastic-net` package in R and optimizing it using `caret`. I read the book introduction to statistical learning in R and am currently trying to predict ordinal data while also trying to feature select the the most important features. I have manufactured fake data from a questionnaire that is in the `likert` [package](https://github.com/jbryer/likert) where users answered the `dep` variable between 1 to 4

When i run my code below i seem to get a list of coefficients for each ordered factor. Can anyone explain to me what they mean. Is it just a case that people who select a specific answer in ordered factors have co-efficients specific to those factors.
Below is the reproducible example i created for this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated in the interpretation of the model

```
# https://github.com/jbryer/likert
library(likert)
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
data(pisaitems)
set.seed(5555)

# Create fake factors by taking the mean of values
# Select only the factors and an dep value for the item we are trying to   predict
# Make the target be an ordered factor
mydf <- dplyr::select(pisaitems, 1:11) %>% 
  dplyr::sample_frac(0.02) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(CNT = as.factor(CNT)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(fct1 = rowMeans(dplyr::select(.,2:3)),
                fct2 = rowMeans(dplyr::select(.,4:7)),
                fct3 = rowMeans(dplyr::select(.,7:9)),
                dep = as.ordered(ST24Q10)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(CNT, matches('fct'), dep)

indep <- as.matrix(dplyr::select(mydf, CNT, starts_with('fct')))
dep <- mydf$dep


mod_glm <- glmnet(x=indep, y = dep, family = "multinomial",
                  lambda = 0, alpha = 0.2,
                  maxit = 1000000,
                  standardize.response=TRUE)
summary(mod_glm)
coef(mod_glm)
```

### Output

```
$`1`
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept)  1.7913750
CNT         -0.3322836
fct1        -0.4241264
fct2        -1.5737877
fct3         1.0554934

$`2`
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept)  0.2820534
CNT          .        
fct1         .        
fct2        -0.6104745
fct3         0.5224429

$`3`
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                      1
(Intercept)  0.60560948
CNT          0.06499997
fct1         0.06013778
fct2         0.45797484
fct3        -0.56307924

$`4`
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                    1
(Intercept) -2.679038
CNT          0.117543
fct1         0.115343
fct2         1.726287
fct3        -1.014857
```

Comment: Is tuning the elastic net and all that caret stuff really part of the problem or could you reproduce it with a single model fit using made up $\alpha$ and $\lambda$? It shouldn’t matter to have non-optimized hyperparameters if your only concern is coefficient interpretation

Comment: Hi @Chaconne, I will reproduce it without the caret optimization part today

Comment: I think most things would be clear after reading glmnet vignette https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html The coefficients in glmnet means the same as they mean in any linear model

Comment: Thank you @rep_ho, I had read the article previously before posting to SO. It is still not clear to me why i have four sets of coefficients for each item I am predicting. I have found [this](http://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html) which states `For most classification models, each predictor will have a separate variable importance for each class (the exceptions are classification trees, bagged trees and boosted trees)` If this is the case is what my GLM is saying that depending on the class, different factors matter more?

Comment: For example in the case of class 2 `CNT` and `fct1` don't matter at all in the prediction of the class (assuming the algorithm is optimized and has good predictive powers) but they do matter in the case of class 4

Comment: Oh, I get your question now (i think). Since you have multiple classes, multinomial logistic regression, which glmnet implements basically fit a separate model for each class in one vs all fashion, so you have 4 sets of coefficients because you have basically 4 models. Not every multinomial logistic regression works like this, sometimes oyu have number.of.classes-1 models.

Comment: Ah ok, so the coefficents themselves should be interpreted in a similiar fashion as a logistic regression in a one vs all manner? If this is the case, could you rewrite your response as an answer and il mark it correct. Thanks for helping me out with this, It has been troubling me for a bit